# How can i call functions of a class inside a php script?

Tags: php, function, class

I have another script 'DBSetting.php' where I assign the data needed to connect to my MySQL database.
But how exactly can I make my script call a function when I try to write "fetchAll();" at the end, it shows me the following error :

> *PHP Parse error: syntax error unexpected 'fetchAll' (T_STRING), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST) in
>   /path/to/script/DBclass.php on line x*

```
<?php    
require_once( 'DBSettings.php' );
class DBClass extends DatabaseSettings
{
    var $classQuery;
    var $link;

    var $errno = '';
    var $error = '';

    // Connects to the database
    function DBClass()
    {

        $settings = DatabaseSettings::getSettings();

        $host = $settings['dbhost'];
        $name = $settings['dbname'];
        $user = $settings['dbusername'];
        $pass = $settings['dbpassword'];

        $this->link = new mysqli( $host , $user , $pass , $name );
    }
    function fetchAll( $result , $resultType = MYSQLI_ASSOC )
    {
        return $result->fetch_all( $resultType );
    }   
}

?>
```

I only want to get some output, if I run the script per command line via PHP DBclass.php it doesn't give me an error and behaves normally -> since it contains only functions of course

Comment: Are you thinking about method chaining?

Comment: How do you "run" that script? It should not execute anything

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it understood what you are trying to achieve, so two things:

You can call the `fetchAll()` method by doing something like this (not tested!):

```
<?php    
require_once( 'DBSettings.php' );
class DBClass extends DatabaseSettings
{
    var $classQuery;
    var $link;

    var $errno = '';
    var $error = '';

    // Connects to the database
    function __construct()
    {

        $settings = DatabaseSettings::getSettings();

        $host = $settings['dbhost'];
        $name = $settings['dbname'];
        $user = $settings['dbusername'];
        $pass = $settings['dbpassword'];

        $this->link = new mysqli( $host , $user , $pass , $name );
    }

    function query( $link )
    {
        return mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT * FROM your_table');
    }

    function fetchAll( $result , $resultType = MYSQLI_ASSOC )
    {
        return $result->fetch_all( $resultType );
    }   
}

?>
```

And in another file:

```
$db_class = new DBClass();
$query = $db_class->query($db_class->link);
var_dump($db_class->fetchAll($query));
```

Comment: What is 'var' for?  As far as I know PHP has no 'var' command.

Comment: That's an old way of defining class properties, by default it will be translated to "public":
https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php

Comment: Thanks for the link.  Since I wasn't doing PHP in version 4, I didn't know about it.